# A regex in SQL or Spark (Scala)

Tags: sql, regex, apache-spark

I am a new developer in Spark Scala. I am not familiar with Regex but I want to write a regex that can extract an ID like this :

```
abcd_mss5884_mww020_025_b => mss5884
abv_c_e_mss478_mww171_172 => mss478
abv_c_e_mww171_172  => otherwise, return THE SAME input string
```

So, in our input string, I should return the first characters starting from "mss...." and stop when I find the first "_" after the "mss" of course (i should ignore the other underscores).

How can I do this please ?
Should I use a regex ? A regex in SQL or in Scala ?
Or should I just use a simple substring method ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [`regexp_extract`](https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/api/sql/#regexp_extract) function. Something like this:

```
val df = Seq(("abcd_mss5884_mww020_025_b"), ("abv_c_e_mss478_mww171_172"), ("abv_c_e_mww171_172")).toDF("input")

df.withColumn("ID", regexp_extract($"input", "^(.*)(mss[^_]+)_(.*)$", 2))
  .withColumn("ID", when($"ID" =!= "", $"ID").otherwise($"input"))
  .show()
```

```
+-------------------------+------------------+
|input                    |ID                |
+-------------------------+------------------+
|abcd_mss5884_mww020_025_b|mss5884           |
|abv_c_e_mss478_mww171_172|mss478            |
|abv_c_e_mww171_172       |abv_c_e_mww171_172|
+-------------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: @blackbishop can you please explain the functionality of `regexp_extract($"input", "^(.*)(mss[^_]+)_(.*)$", 2))`.

Comment: @venus it extracts from the input string the part corresponding to the second group from the regex (as there are 3 groups in the regex).